# Apache configuration, Setting document root or virtual host

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, lamp, opensuse

how can I say to apache to go to look in the /home/user/Web folder for the project without missing the possibility to display localhost/phpMyAdmin. Itried with Alias, Document root an Virtual Host.

Comment: add a new site configuration to /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Comment: There is something called 'mod_userdir'...

Comment: And yes, that can be done by all three things you mentioned. You say you failed. So: what have you tried?

Comment: I tryed mod_userdir changing path of directory but it didn't work

Comment: I have no sites-avaiable folder.